# Teamviewer - Find out ID of remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm connected to a Ubuntu 13.04 Raring ringtail Server, I'm setting up. I've just installed Teamviewer on it (Through SSH), started daemon, and it's running fine.

However, I'd like to know if there is some way to know what's that machine ID on teamviewer, from the command-line (some file I should look for, etc...) since I'm working only by prompt (ssh)

Comment: Have you set up an account? If so, in the **Computers & Contacts** box you can right-click on the machine and the ID is under **Properties**. You can do this from either the client or through the Web Login link on TeamViewer's home page.

Comment: Yes i have an account, but this Teamviewer instance I just installed from prompt (ssh) can't login or whatever, I want the ID to add it to my account, but from prompt i can't see anything, so i wanna know if there's some configuration file i should look for...

Comment: Found it, it is on /opt/teamviewer9/config/global.conf , i have the ID, now i need to login into my account from prompt lol, don't know if that is possible.

Comment: You can add the ID to your account from the Web Login.

Comment: Yes, did that already, but can't login from prompt in the remote server, so i'll wait til monday to ask for it, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad you've sorted it. Thanks for the location of the settings file: I'll squirrel away the information for future reference.